# What are the chances of Math.random returning 0?

Tags: javascript, random, floating-point

Like the asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15830658/9513577), I was wondering why `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)` was not preferred over `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1`, and found that it was because Math.random has a tiny (but relevant) chance of returning 0 exactly. But how tiny?

Further research told me that [this random number is accurate to 16 decimal places... well, sort of.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3344463/9513577) And it's the "sort of" that I'm curious about.

I understand that floating point numbers work differently to decimals. I struggle with the specifics though. If the number were a strict decimal value, I believe the chances would be one in ten billiard (or ten quadrillion, in the American system) - 1:10<sup>16</sup>.

Is this correct, or have I messed up, or does the floating point thing make a difference?

Comment: Why does returning zero from `Math.random` matter to you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As I mentioned in the question, it has implications for using it to generate random integers. I *could* go with the common way of doing things (using .floor...+1 instead of .ceil) but I'd like to know if it's *actually* necessary to prevent inaccuracies (or code potentially breaking every 1 in a billiard iterations). Plus it may have implications on the *actual* randomness of this method.

Comment: A possible hackish fix: Check for exact equality to zero, and, if true, then add whatever the smallest possible number is in JavaScript.  This would have _almost_ a negligible effect on the distribution, I think, but would avoid the zero problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mean, yeah, but adding in an `if (result == 0){result =+ Number.MIN_VALUE}` seems more unwieldy than just going `.floor...+1`. Interesting to note though.

Comment: what about `Math.ceil((Math.random() + Number.MIN_VALUE) * 10)`

Comment: d'oh ... `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) || 1`

Comment: @JaromandaX the first one has a similarly miniscule chance of going higher than the established bounds, and the second one... I'm not sure how that would work... what are the conditions for returning 1 instead of 0? Also I think the chance of 0 comes out of the chance of 10, so I'd imagine you'd need `|| 10`...

Comment: First one won't go over maximum. Try plugging in 1 instead of random

Comment: In fact you can use 1e-17 instead of minvalue due to the number of significant digits in a JavaScript number

Comment: @JaromandaX h-uh. Why though? 10.00...1 rounded up is 11... Now I'm even more confused!

Comment: Significant digits

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript is a dialect of ECMAScript. The [ECMAScript-262 standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-math.random) fails to specify `Math.random` precisely. The relevant clause says:

> ### Math.random ( )
>
> Returns a [Number value](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#number-value) with positive sign, greater than or equal to **+0** but strictly less than **1**, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an [implementation-defined](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#implementation-defined) algorithm or strategy. This function takes no arguments.
>
> Each `Math.random` function created for distinct [realms](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#realm) must produce a distinct sequence of values from successive calls.

In the absence of a complete specification, no definitive statement can be made about the probability of `Math.random` returning zero. Each ECMAScript implementation may choose a different algorithm and need not provide a truly uniform distribution.

ECMAScript uses the IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point format for its `Number` type. In this format, the significand (fraction portion) of the number has 53 bits. Every floating-point number has the form *s* • *f* • 2<sup>*e*</sup>, where *s* (for sign) is +1 or −1, *f* (for fraction) is the significand and is an integer in [0, 2<sup>53</sup>), and *e* (for exponent) is an integer in [−1074, 971]. The number is said to be normalized if the high bit of *f* is set (so *f* is in [2<sup>52</sup>, 2<sup>53</sup>)). Since negative numbers are not a concern in this answer, let *s* be implicitly +1 for the rest of this answer.

One issue with distributing random numbers in [0, 1) is that the representable values are not evenly spaced. There are 2<sup>52</sup> representable values in [½, 1)—all those with *f* in [2<sup>52</sup>, 2<sup>53</sup>) and *e* = −53. And there are the same number of values in [¼, ½)—all those with *f* in [2<sup>52</sup>, 2<sup>53</sup>) and *e* = −54. Since there are the same number of numbers in this interval but the interval is half as long, the numbers are more closely spaced. Similarly, in [⅛, ¼), the spacing halves again. This continues until the exponent reaches −1074, at which point the normal numbers end with *f* = 2<sup>52</sup>. The numbers smaller than that are said to be subnormal (or zero), with *f* in [0, 2<sup>52</sup>) and *e* = −1074, and they are evenly spaced.

One choice about how to distribute the numbers for `Math.random` is to use only the set of evenly spaced numbers *f* • 2<sup>−53</sup> for *f* in [0, 2<sup>53</sup>). This uses all the representable values in [½, 1), but only half the values in [¼, ½), one-fourth the values in [⅛, ¼), and so on. This is simple and avoids some oddities in the distribution. If implemented correctly, the probability zero is produced is one in 2<sup>53</sup>.

Another choice is to use all the representable values in [0, 1), each with probability proportional to the distance from it to the next higher representable value. Thus, each representable number in [½, 1) would be chosen with probability 1/2<sup>53</sup>, each representable number in [¼, ½) would be chosen with probability 1/2<sup>54</sup>, each representable number in [⅛, ¼) would be chosen with probability 1/2<sup>55</sup>, and so on. This distribution approximates a uniform distribution on the reals and provides finer precision where the floating-point format is finer. If implemented correctly, the probability zero is produced is one in 2<sup>1074</sup>.

Another choice is to use all the representable values in [0, 1), each with probability proportional to the length of the segment in which the representable value is the nearest representable value of all the real numbers in the segment. I will omit discussion of some details of this distribution except to say it mimics the results one would get by choosing a real number with uniform distribution and then rounding it to a representable value using the round-to-nearest-ties-to-even rule. If implemented correctly, the probability zero is produced is one in 2<sup>1075</sup>. (One problem with this distribution is that a uniform distribution over the reals in [0, 1) will sometimes produce a number so close to 1 that rounding produces 1. This then requires either that `Math.random` be allowed to return 1 or that the distribution be fudged in some way, perhaps by returning the next lower representable value instead of 1.)

I will note that the ECMAScript specification is sufficiently lax that one might assert that `Math.random` may distribute the numbers with equal probability for each representable value, ignoring the spacing between them. This would not mimic a uniform distribution over the real numbers at all, and I expect very few people would favor it. However, if implemented, the probability zero is returned is one in 1021 • 2<sup>52</sup>, because there are 2<sup>52</sup> normalized numbers with exponents from −53 to −1074 (1020 values of *e*), and 2<sup>52</sup> subnormal or zero numbers.