# JavaScript - random word generator

Tags: javascript, math

Am curious why is `math.floor` returns good results than `math.ceil` when I do random words generation and check in `console.log`.

Why can't `math.ceil` work perfectly? Is there something about incompatibility of `math.ceil` with `math.random` or is it how I assign and array number (item) of string elements?

Answer (score 6):

`Math.random()` returns a number less than one (non-inclusive) but greater than 0 (inclusive)

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); // returns a random integer from 0 to 9

Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10); // returns a random integer from 0 to 10 with a very low chance of 0
```

If `Math.random` results in `0` exactly, both `Math.floor()` and `Math.ceil()` will return `0`, but if `Math.random()` results in `0.00000001`, `Math.floor()` returns `0` and `Math.ceil()` returns `1`.

Comment: `Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)` return 1 to 10

Comment: @MBadrian As explained, because of the way `Math.random()` works, `Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)` can return 0 but with an extremely low probability (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089553)

Answer (score 0):

if you use `Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)` you lost first number and if you use `Math.floor(Math.random()*10)` you lost last  Number 
but if you use `Math.round(Math.random()*10)` you can find 0 to 10 Number

```js
var k=2.1
console.log(Math.ceil(k))
console.log(Math.floor(k))
console.log(Math.round(k))
 k=2.6
console.log(Math.ceil(k))
console.log(Math.floor(k))
console.log(Math.round(k))
```

Comment: Problem with `Math.round()` is that it has unbalanced probabilities for numbers on the end:

`0-0.49 => 0` (Probability: 1/6) 
`0.5-1.49 => 1` (Probability: 1/3) 
`1.5-2.49 => 2` (Probability: 1/3) 
`2.5-3 => 3` (Probability: 1/6)