# Hey! Why my Javascript code is not working

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a function in Javascript that will give a random integer between two integers (including both).
But, unfortunately this is not including the first integer.
The code is as follows:

```
const randomEjector = (num1,num2) => {return Math.ceil(Math.random() * (num2 - num1)) + num1}
```

I am considering the analogy of inequality.
++
Let's consider,
(`Math.random()` will output a no. between 0(**including**) and 1(**excluding**)).
Let's say `x = Math.random()`, then **x∈[0,1)**
So, **`0 ≤ x < 1`** 
**`0 * (num2-num1) ≤ x * (num2-num1) < 1 * (num2-num1)`**
Again, **`x*(num2-num1)∈[0,1*(num2-num1))`**
Now opening `Math.ceil()` part:

But, `Math.ceil()` is like **greatest integer function**:
So, for **(0,1] it will return 1**.
for **0 => 0**
and for `interval ((num2-num1)-1,(num2-num1))`,it will return **(num2-num1)**.
So, After `Math.ceil()` is executed, we should be left with an interval **[0,(num2-num1)]**.
Now, `x*num2-num1`∈ **[0,(num2-num1)]**
Finally, `let y = x*(num2-num1)`
So,`0 ≤ y ≤ (num2-num1)`
So,`0 + num1 ≤  y + num1 ≤ (num2-num1) + num1`
Which will give `num1 ≤ y + num1 ≤  num2`
Let, `z = y + num1`
So, `z ∈ [num1,num2]`
**Then, why my function is excluding 1st term and making it like (num1,num2]?**
**Where's the problem?**
For instance for `console.log(randomEjector(3,4))`, it will always give 4 and never 3.

Comment: [What are the chances of Math.random returning 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089553/what-are-the-chances-of-math-random-returning-0)

Answer (score 4):

It's unspeakably unlikely that `Math.random()` will ever return exactly 0, so `Math.ceil(Math.random())` will unspeakably likely always return 1.

In other words, `randomEjector(3,4)` will, once in a very, very blue moon, give you 3.

Comment: Ok, that means Math.random() can never generate 0. Thank you.

Comment: @Xeroid No, it _can_ generate 0. The odds are just ridiculously slim. ([Around one in 2^1075](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52095861/479156).)

Comment: I got another query too.  
`let myNumbers = [100,998,997];`
`const nestedArray = [];`
`const newNumber = myNumbers.map((value)=>{`
    `if(value>400){`
        `nestedArray.push(value);`
    `}`
    `return nestedArray;`
`})`
`console.log(newNumber);`

I am expecting the output to be **[[ 998, 997 ]]** but getting **[[ 998, 997 ],[ 998, 997 ],[ 998, 997 ]]**

Comment: @Xeroid New questions go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). (That is, after you have done enough research yourself first to find the answer.)

Comment: So, if i will run my code for 2^1075 times making my browser lag and then, I will get 3. Of all, it might take more than a year too.

Comment: @Xeroid I'm no mathematician, but I think you'll need more time than the universe exists. And even then, it is random. So there is a decent chance you don't even guess it after that time.

Answer (score -1):

It returns 4 because you are always ceiling the result, if you want it to return 4 then you need to floor the result.

Comment: But, Math.ceil() is like greatest integer function. When, 3 is integer, Math.ceil(3) will return 3.Ok,,since, Math.random() will never return 0 and hence, my output will never be 3 and always be 4. I got it now. Thank You.