# Math.ceil ; Math.random

Tags: javascript, math, random, ceil

Here's a very basic issue that i cannot resolve on my mind:

In JS if i do:

Math.random() i will get random numbers between 0 and 1 (including 0, not including 1)

So, if i do Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100) i will get random numbers between 0 and 100. Am i right?

I will get 0 if Math.random() was exactly 0, which is possible as i read in the documentation.

However I read everywhere that doing this "Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)" i will get numbers between 1 and 100.

Please, can someone clarify this situation?

Thanks!

Math.random () -> [0; 1)
Math.ceil(Math.random()) -> [0; 100]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the chances of Math.random returning 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089553/what-are-the-chances-of-math-random-returning-0)

Comment: `0.9900000000000001 * 100 = 99.00000000000001` and the ceiling of `99.00000000000001` is `100`, so anything above `0.99` will result in `100`

Comment: if you, for example, try to excecute Math.ceil(0.1) or Math.ceil(0.2) primitives values, you'll always get 1 as a result of calling the `.ceil`. Therefore, you'll always get the 100% or 1 (it's the same)

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero the OP is multiplying by 100 *before* rounding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.random()` will give you a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive), but the chance that it's exactly 0 is incredibly low.

`Math.ceil()` rounds up. Given that the chances you get exactly 0 are astronomically low, you will likely get something above 0 from `Math.random()`, so it's *almost* (but not entirely) impossible to get 0 from `Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)`.

So `Math.ceil(Math.random()*100))` will give you a tiny tiny chance to get 0, but usually between 1 and 100 (inclusive).

Usually what you want to do is `Math.floor()`, which rounds down. It doesn't have this edge case because `Math.random()` never gives you `1` so there's never a small chance that `Math.floor(Math.random()*100))` gives you 100. It's always 0-99 inclusive evenly distributed.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted you by mistake and didn't see it until a few minutes had passed, so I cant undo it until the post is edited.

Comment: Its very strange I got *2* downvotes for this though. Is it just people piling on? I thought it was kind of an interesting answer.. wtf

Comment: It is an interesting answer. I must have accidentally downvoted when changing windows.