# Can you make a non-cryptographically secure random number generator secure?

Tags: javascript, random

This is more of a fundamental question, but the context is specifically in terms of JavaScript. Given that `Math.random` is not cryptographically secure, can the results still be considered secure when it has been called a certain number of times that cannot be predicted?

So if I was to generate a 32bit number using `window.crypto.getRandomValues` for example and select one of the digits as an iteration count – calling `Math.random` that number of times and using the last result, is the result still predictable?

The purpose of this is to generate a set of secure random numbers between 0 and 1 (exclusive) without having the ability to manually seed `Math.random`.

My initial thoughts are that the result shouldn't be predictable – but I want to make sure I'm not overlooking something crucial.

Comment: no, it's easy to run random() billions of times until a known pattern is observed, then each number it will make can be predicted ahead of time from that point; adding 0-9 extra checks won't matter. you know about `window.crypto.getRandomValues`, so use it if you need a CSPRNG, don't roll your own crypto. you can use fast+slow timers, like the time methods at https://github.com/rndme/rndme

Comment: If you're going to use `window.crypto.getRandomValues`, why not just use its output directly instead of bringing `Math.random` into the picture?

Comment: Well as mentioned in the question, my purpose is to generate a set of secure random numbers between 0 and 1 (exclusive). Is there a way to achieve this with only `window.crypto.getRandomValues`, leaving `Math.random` out of the equation and get a good distribution of values?

Comment: ^ Found one possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18230432/2905686

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Let's start with a warning; just in case

Honestly, I'm not sure why you would want to use something beyond `window.crypto.getRandomValues` (or its Linux equivalent `/dev/random`). If you're planning to "stretch" its output for some reason, chances are you're doing it wrong. Whatever your scenario is, don't hardcode such a seed seed into your script before serving it to clients. Not even if your `.js` file is created dynamically on the server side. That would be as if you would push encrypted data together with your encryption key… voiding any security gains in its root.

That being said, let's look at your question in your line of thinking…

#### About your idea

The output of `math.random` is insecure as it produces predictable outputs. Meaning: having a sequence of outputs, an attacker can successfully recover the state and the following outputs it will produce. Seeding it with a cryptographically secure seed from `window.crypto.getRandomValues` (or its Linux equivalent `/dev/random`) will **not** fix that problem.

As a securer approach you might want to take a look at ChaCha20, which is a cryptographically secure stream cipher. It definitely produces securer outputs than `math.random` and I've seen several pure vanilla implementation of ChaCha20 at Github et al. So, using something "safer" than `math.random` shouldn't be   all too hard to implement in your script(s). Seed ChaCha20 with `window.crypto.getRandomValues` (or its Linux equivalent `/dev/random`) as you were planning to do and you're set.

### But…

Please note that I haven't dived into the *use of Javascript for crypto purposes* itself. Doing so tends to introduce attack vectors. Which is why you'ld (at least) need HTTPS when your project is served online. I'll have to skip mentioning all the other related nitpicks… mainly because you didn't mention such details in your question, but also to prevent this answer from getting too broad/long. A quick search at Security.SE tends to enlighten you about using-Javascript-for-crypto related issues.

## Instead - use the Web Cryptographic API

Last but not least, I'ld like to get back to what I said for starters and point you to the fact that you might as well simply use `window.crypto.getRandomValues` (or its Linux equivalent `/dev/random`) for all randomness purposes. The speed gains of not doing so are minimal in most scenarios.

Crypto is hard… don't break your neck trying to solve problems on your own. Even for Javascript, an applicable solution already exist:

## Web Cryptographic API - Example:

```
/* assuming that window.crypto.getRandomValues is available */

var array = new Uint32Array(10);
window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
console.log("Your lucky numbers:");
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

See, most modern browsers support a minimum of CryptoAPI which allows your clients to call `obj.getRandomValues()` from within Javascript - which is practically a call to the system's `getRandomValues` or `/dev/random`.

- [The WebCrypto API was enabled by default starting in Chrome 37 (August 26, 2014)](https://www.chromium.org/blink/webcrypto)
- [Mozilla Firefox supports it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource)
- [Internet Explorer 11 supports it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302338(v=vs.85).aspx)
- etc.

#### Some final words regarding polyfills

If you really must support outdated browsers, decent polyfills can close the gap. But when it comes to security, both "using old browsers" as well as "using polyfills" is a nightmare waiting to go wrong. Instead, be professional and educate clients about the fact that its easier to upgrade to a newer browser, than to pick up polyfills and the problems that come with them.

Murphy's Law applies here: *When using polyfills for security/cryptography, what can go wrong will go wrong!*

In the end, its always better to be safe and not use polyfills just to support some outdated browsers, than to be sorry when stuff hits the fan. A browser update will cost your client a few minutes. A cryptographic polyfill that fails ruins your reputation forever. Remember that!

Comment: what do you think of `performance.now().toString().split(".")[1][0];` for a random single digit? (the current tenth of a millisecond)

Comment: @dandavis Personally? Don't do it. // Cryptographically? Don't do it. // Logically? Perf counters (here: clocking ms value) are a tiny part of what the system feeds to its internal secure random pool. Seems not logic to limit randomness sources to a performance counter or anything else when you can have a whole pool full of different (let's just call it) noise sources. Besides, it's hard to outperform a system native randomness pool with a Javascript line like that (especially when it splits stuff et al.)

Comment: thanks. some folks don't trust OS-provided randomness, so i ask around. The slow-clock timer methods is unpredictable, probably the most important but certainly not the only part of a CSPRNG...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple Math.random()-style CSPRNG drop-in:

```
Math.randomer=function(){
  return crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / Math.pow(2,32);
};

// usage demo:
alert(Math.randomer());
```

Unlike the unsafe random(), this code will still rate-limit because of the use of crypto.getRandomValues, but that's probably a good thing, and you can get dozens of KBs a second with this.