# Hashing algorithm that generates characters with specified limits and rules

Tags: javascript, algorithm, encryption, hash

I would like to have a hashing algorithm, that can generate a hash string but with alphanumeric characters but under a specified limit.

For example, If I provide it some text, it should generate a string that can be used as a password for websites. So at least 8 characters long, must contain at least a capital letter and at least a number.

Is there any hash algorithm like this? or would I have to create a custom implementation? or is it not possible at all?

I'd like to do this in javascript

Comment: Hash algorithms are producing bytes. Take the bytes and convert whatever you want.

Comment: Do you need it to be cryptographically secure? Requiring "at least one" capital letter and number is problematic, because it causes a dependence between the bytes in your output. Would it suffice to just generate a hash (long enough for your security purposes) using an established hash algorithm and then add "A1" at the end to ensure it passes the human password requirement?

Comment: @Berthur I guess I can do that. Is there any algorithm that doesn't generate long hashes? Like 16 characters long would be great

Comment: @WorChan If the hash function is cryptographically secure, you can typically just generate a hash and pick an arbitrary subset of it. I do recommend you read properly into the theory though if you are planning to implement something security critical.

Comment: @Berthur Thanks for the advice. Could you please comment some good resources to study more on this?

Comment: @WorChan Unfortunately I don't know any specific resource that I could recommend, perhaps someone else here does :)

Answer (score 1):

> So at least 8 characters long, must contain at least a capital letter and at least a number

1. Generate a random integer that determines the number of capitals, Use `getRandomInt` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18230432/1820553) that uses sampling with rejecting. This uses the `getRandomValues` to [get cryptographically strong random values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues).

   `let capNum = getRandomInt(1,7)`

   One reserved for digits
2. Generate the number of digits.

   `let digNum = getRandomInt(1, 8-capNum)`
3. Now we have `8 - capnum - digNum` amount letters ( not capitals)
4. Generate necessary random elements for each group and store all of them into a string `arr`.
5. Apply [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm so that the order of the characters in the string shuffles.

```js
   var i = arr.length, k , temp;  
   while(--i > 0){
      k = getRandomInt(0, i);
      /swap
      temp = arr[k];
      arr[k] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = temp;
   }
```

Comment: I've only provided the gist of the algorithm. When you finished the full coding, you can post as an answer that I'll upvote.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "Generate necessary random elements for each group and store all of them into a string arr". Sorry, I'm a newbie when it comes to cryptography and hashing algorithms

Comment: Isn't clear? For example; for a digit `a = getRandomInt(0,9)` for a letter `a = getRandomInt(0,26)`  then convert integer to letter...

Answer (score -1):

I didn't say in which language you need the algorithm .

In CSharp:

```
public static string Hash(string password) 
    {
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        using var hash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512.Create();
        {
            var hashedInputBytes = hash.ComputeHash(bytes);

            // Convert to text
            // StringBuilder Capacity is 128, because 512 bits / 8 bits in byte * 2 symbols for byte 
            var hashedInputStringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder(128);
            foreach (var b in hashedInputBytes)
                hashedInputStringBuilder.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
            return hashedInputStringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry I forgot to mention that I'd like the algorithm in Javascript but I'll try to read your code to see if I can convert it to javascript.

Comment: So how does this code ensure at least a capital letter and at least one number ?